# Limiting the scope of ng-repeat in AngularJS1

Tags: angularjs

Let's say that I would use `ng-repeat` and the output would be:

```
   `1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
    10`
```

The numbers 1 to 10 would be fetched from JSON by PHP, from MySQL database (XAMPP - virtual server, REST API). Now, let's say that I need only numbers from 1 to 5 - is there some way in AngularJS1, that by using `ng-repeat`I could output **only** numbers from 1 to 5, but **without manipulating with PHP and MySQL code**?

Let's say that now I have a JSON with numbers; 1 to 31 and that I want to display, by expression, numbers from 8 to 14. Is it possible to somehow ust two `limitTo` filters in one `ng-repeat` directive, which could limit the output of {{expression}} **FROM** **-** **TO** some range of data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add limitTo:5 to ng-repeat .

```
ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:5"
```

And if you want repeat again

```
ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo:5:5"
```

Here is syntax

```
{{ object | limitTo : limit : begin }}
```

> limit :A number, specifying how many elements to return
>
> begin :Optional. A number specifying where to begin the limitation.
>   Default is 0

Answer (score 0):

use the straightforward `limitTo` filter, as natively provided by Angular:

ex:

```
<ul class="list">
  <li ng-repeat="item in list| filter:query | orderBy:orderProp | limitTo:quantity">
    {{item.name}}
  </li>
</ul>
```